# searching data from database..?

Tags: java, database, jsp

i have a project about patient billingsystem which is a website to a  organization..
and i use technologie jsp and java to develop this....

in this system i have different organizations and each organization has it's own database
and i didn't maintain any central database for this system..
and in this my requirement is seraching must be done by the organization wise..

for example if we want to know the no of beds is available in each organization then it has 
gives the result no of beds available by organization wise....

and my thought is that save the organization static ip in my central database 
and then query on the database when we require..

In this also i have a doubt that..
 is it possible to query on different databases on at a time...??

please give me any solution for my problem....

thanks in advance...

Comment: Well, his English might be lacking, but I don't think this is all that bad. Sure there's no code, but he's accurately described a legitimate problem to be solved with technologies the people on this site know how to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If IP is all you have to go on, I guess you have to do it.

I imagine you'd be better off hitting the hostname, since the it's a lot less likely to change.

As far as hitting the different databases, you'll have to make a connection to each one (although it's possible you could cluster them, depending on size, having a couple super nodes that hit all the ones in that state or something to parallelize it) but it's pretty easy to do. I mean, it's almost as simple as this (logically, obviously you can't copy/paste this.)

```
for(DatabaseBinding db : databases) {
    Connection conn = db.spawnConnection();
    Statement stmt = ...
    ResultSet rs = stmt.execute(getBedsQuery());
    List<Bed> beds = processResultSetForBeds(rs);
    allBeds.add(beds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any DBMSs that would let you do a single query that hits multiple database schemas.  Your two best options are:

1. Run a service that knows about each instance (most likely by looking them up in a central database as you say) that can query each database and aggregate the results and return them to your main program.  Once you do this you will most likely find other uses for this central service, like initializing all instances.
2. Run all organizations from a single database schema.  This is called [Multitennant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy).  Add a field to most of your tables for the organization ID and add it to all of your queries and most of your indexes.

Which will work better for you is affected by several factors.

1. How many organizations you're dealing with vs how much data for each
2. If you fairly regularly add or remove organizations, multitennant will mean a lot less administration to do so.
3. If the amount of data varies greatly between organizations, or you have some organizations that are much more active than others, then keeping them in separate database instances will allow you to more finely tune your load balancing and backups.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to query on different databases on at a time?

It depends on what you mean.

- If the databases all use the same schemas, table names and SQL dialect, and if you are not doing updates, and you don't need atomic queries, you can simply keep a pool of database connections to different databases, send the same query to each database, and then manually merge the stuff you pull from the resultsets.
- If the database schemas (or just the table names) are different, then 1) you have to send different queries, and 2) merging the results may be fiddly.
- If the databases use different SQL dialects, you've also got to deal with differences in SQL syntax, column types, and potentially semantics.
- Atomic queries and updates across multiple databases are hard.  You need to use a distributed database layer that supports distributed transactions.

The Wikipedia article on [Federated Database Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_database_system) may help you understand some of the issues.